# IEqualityComparer GetHashCode being called but Equals not

Tags: c#

I have two lists that I am trying to compare. So I have created a class that implements the `IEqualityComparer` interface, please see below in the bottom section of code.

When I step through my code, the code goes through my `GetHashCode` implementation but not the `Equals`? I do not really understand the `GetHashCode` method, despite reading around on the internet and what exactly it is doing.

```
List<FactorPayoffs> missingfactorPayoffList = 
    factorPayoffList.Except(
        factorPayoffListOrg,
        new FactorPayoffs.Comparer()).ToList();

List<FactorPayoffs> missingfactorPayoffListOrg =
    factorPayoffListOrg.Except(
        factorPayoffList,
        new FactorPayoffs.Comparer()).ToList();
```

So in the two lines of code above the two lists return me every item, telling me that the two lists do not contain any items that are the same. This is not true, there is only row that is different. I'm guessing this is happening because the `Equals` method is not getting called which in turns makes me wonder if my `GetHashCode` method is working as its supposed to?

```
class FactorPayoffs
    {
        public string FactorGroup { get; set; }
        public string Factor { get; set; }
        public DateTime dtPrice { get; set; }
        public DateTime dtPrice_e { get; set; }
        public double Ret_USD { get; set; }

        public class Comparer : IEqualityComparer<FactorPayoffs>
        {
            public bool Equals(FactorPayoffs x, FactorPayoffs y)
            {                    
                return x.dtPrice == y.dtPrice && 
                    x.dtPrice_e == y.dtPrice_e && 
                    x.Factor == y.Factor && 
                    x.FactorGroup == y.FactorGroup;
            }

            public int GetHashCode(FactorPayoffs obj)
            {
                int hash = 17;
                hash = hash * 23 + (obj.dtPrice).GetHashCode();
                hash = hash * 23 + (obj.dtPrice_e).GetHashCode();
                hash = hash * 23 + (obj.Factor ?? "").GetHashCode();
                hash = hash * 23 + (obj.FactorGroup ?? "").GetHashCode();
                hash = hash * 23 + (obj.Ret_USD).GetHashCode();
                return hash;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The `GetHashCode` implementation has to return the same value when two instances are considered equal. It should try to return different numbers when they are not equal but this is of lower importance.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Your `Equals` and `GetHashCode` implementations should involve the exact same set of properties; they do not.

In more formal terms, `GetHashCode` **must always** return the same value for two objects that compare equal. With your current code, two objects that differ only in the `Ret_USD` value will always compare equal but are not guaranteed to have the same hash code.

So what happens is that LINQ calls `GetHashCode` on two objects you consider equal, gets back different values, concludes that since the values were different the objects cannot be equal so there's no point at all in calling `Equals` and moves on.

To fix the problem, either remove the `Ret_USD` factor from `GetHashCode` or introduce it also inside `Equals` (whatever makes sense for your semantics of equality).

Comment: thanks - it now works. Think I need to read more on hashcodes, I'm not understanding how they are being generated

Comment: @mHelpMe [Here's a valuable link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode.aspx)

Comment: @mHelpMe, aslo, arithmetic should be unchecked and avoid pointless null coalescence, http://stackoverflow.com/a/22453411/659190

Comment: Link in previous comment didn't work for me. I'm guessing it was this one https://ericlippert.com/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode/

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: Your link is broken. Updated link is here: [Guidelines and rules for GetHashCode](https://ericlippert.com/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode/). It is really a must read for all developers.

Answer (score 15):

`GetHashCode` is intended as a fast but rough estimate of equality, so many operations potentially involving large numbers of comparisons start by checking this result instead of `Equals`, and only use `Equals` when necessary. In particular, if `x.GetHashCode()!=y.GetHashCode()`, then we already know `x.Equals(y)` is false, so there is no reason to call `Equals`. Had `x.GetHashCode()==y.GetHashCode()`, then `x` *might* equal `y`, but only a call to `Equals` will give a definite answer.

If you implement `GetHashCode` in a way that causes `GetHashCode` to be different for two objects where `Equals` returns `true`, then you have a bug in your code and many collection classes and algorithms relying on these methods will silently fail.

Comment: One of the best and yet concise explanation of `GetHashCode()` I have ever seen.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to force the execution of the Equals you can implement it as follows

```
public int GetHashCode(FactorPayoffs obj) {
        return 1;
    }
```

Comment: This is an easy workaround but be careful when using this approach. When used within a tight loop, this can cause serious performance penalties since you are bypassing the `GetHashCode()` method for all objects.

Answer (score 3):

Rewrite you `GetHashCode` implementation like this, to match the semantics of your `Equals` implementation.

```
public int GetHashCode(FactorPayoffs obj)
{
    unchecked
    {
            int hash = 17;
            hash = hash * 23 + obj.dtPrice.GetHashCode();
            hash = hash * 23 + obj.dtPrice_e.GetHashCode();
            if (obj.Factor != null)
            {
                hash = hash * 23 + obj.Factor.GetHashCode();
            }

            if (obj.FactorGroup != null)
            {
                hash = hash * 23 + obj.FactorGroup.GetHashCode();
            }

            return hash;
    }
}
```

Note, you should use `unchecked` because you don't care about overflows. Additionaly, coalescing to `string.Empty` is pointlessy wasteful, just exclude from the hash.

See [here for the best generic answer I know](https://stackoverflow.com/a/263416/659190),