# Need help understanding unexpected behavior using LINQ Join with HashSet<T>

Tags: c#, linq, join, inner-join, hashset

I encountered some odd behavior using C# HastSet with LINQ's Join method that I don't understand. I've simplified what I am doing to help focus on the behavior I am seeing.

I have the following:

```
 private HashSet<MyClass> _mySet; // module level

 IEnumerable<ISearchKey> searchKeys; // parameter.
 // Partial key searches are allowed.

 private IEqualityComparer<ICoreKey> _coreKeyComparer; // Module level.
 // Compares instances of MyClass and ISearchKey to determine 
 // if they match.
```

### Given that

1. There is a 1-to-many relationship between searchKeys and _mySet.
2. MyClass implements interface IPartialKey and ICoreKey.
3. ISearchKey inherits from IPartialKey and ICoreKey.
4. MyClass and ISearchKey instance both override the GetHashCode method.
5. MyClass's hash code value is based on its full key value, which
       includes its ICoreKey and IPartialKey values plus other fields.
6. The full keys used by MyClass are not unique.  Two different MyClass instances can have the same hash code.
7. ISearchKey's hash code value is based only on its ICoreKey and
       IPartialKey values. i.e. The ISearchKey hash code might differ from
       the hash code for a matching MyClass instance. (Side note: in the case where I first
       encountered the problem, the ISearchKey's IPartialKey values match
       the MyClass full key, so the GetHashCode methods would return the
       same value for both ISearchKey and MyClass.  I included the
       additional complexity to better illustrate the underlying logic on
       what I am doing.)
8. The _coreKeyComparer.GetHashCode method returns
       the same value for matching instances of ISearchKey and MyClass using
       only their ICoreKey values.
9. The _coreKeyComparer.Equals method cast
       the parameters to MyClass and ISearchKey respectively and returns
       true if their IPartialKey values match.  (Side note:
       _coreKeyComparer has been HEAVILY tested and works correctly.)

### I expected a join between the two collections should result in something like:

```
{searchKey_a, myClass_a1},
{searchKey_a, myClass_a2},
{searchKey_a, myClass_a3},
{searchKey_b, myClass_b1},
{searchKey_b, myClass_b2},
{searchKey_c, myClass_c1},
{searchKey_c, myClass_c2},
{searchKey_c, myClass_c3},
{searchKey_c, myClass_c4},
etc....
```

i.e The same ISearchKey instance would occur multiple times, once for each matching MyClass instance it is joined to.

### But when I do a join from searchKeys to _mySet:

```
        var matchedPairs = searchKeys
          .Join(
            _mySet,
            searchKey => searchKey,
            myClass => myClass,
            (searchKey, myClass) => new {searchKey, myClass},
            _coreKeyComparer)
            .ToList();
```

I only get one MyClass instance per searchKeyClass instance. i.e. The matchedPairs collection looks like:

```
    {searchKey_a, myClass_a1},
    {searchKey_b, myClass_b1},
    {searchKey_c, myClass_c1},
etc....
```

### However if I reverse the join, go from _mySet to searchKeys:

```
   var matchedPairs = _mySet
          .Join(
            searchKeys,
            myClass => myClass,
            searchKey => searchKey,
            (myClass, searchKey) => new {searchKey, myClass},
            _coreKeyComparer)
            .ToList();
```

I get the correct matchedPairs collection. All the matching records from _mySet are returned along with the searchKey which they matched against.

I checked the documentation and examined multiple examples and don't see any reason why the searchKeys-to-_mySet Join gives the wrong answer, while the _mySet-to-searchKeys gives the correct/different answer.

(Side note: I also tried GroupJoin from searchKeys to _myset and go similiar results. i.e. Each searchKeyClass instance found at most one result from _mySet.)

Either I don't understand how the Join method is supposed to work, or Join works differently with HashSet than it does with List or other type of collection.

If the former, I need clarification so I don't make mistakes using Join in the future.

If the latter, then is this differing behavior a .Net bug, or is this the correct behavior with HashSet?

Assuming the behavior is correct, I would greatly appreciate someone explaining the underlying logic behind this (unexpected) Join/HashSet behavior.

Just to be clear, I've already fixed my code so it return the correct results, I just want to understand why I got incorrect results initially.

Comment: I'm not familiar with different behavior using `Join` with any different type of enumerable, `List<T>`, `HashSet<T>`, `T[]`, etc should all behave the same.

Comment: I believe your comparer violates the requirements for a comparer: [In more formal terms, GetHashCode must always return the same value for two objects that compare equal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22453152/2557128).

Comment: @NetMage: The comparer DOES return the same hash code value for matching values. That is item 8 in my Givens list.

Comment: Without seeing more of your code, and ideally a *small, simple, complete example that I can actually run on my machine*, it is hard to know what you are doing wrong. Your statement "Either I don't understand Join or Join is broken" is likely incorrect; probably there is a bug in your comparison logic. This attitude that the bug is not in your crazy code but is in well-tested, simple framework code has a name, in fact it is called "select isn't broken".

Comment: @RBDavidson That isn't what I was stating: will `GetHashCode` always return the same value for values that are `Equal`, given they are based on different fields?

Comment: @EricLippert I don't have an attitude on this, nor did I claim there wasn't a problem in my code.  I asked for help in understanding what the problem is. I never said Join is broken, but it is working differently with HashSet than I've seen with other collection types. I *asked* if the difference is defined behavior or an unintended bug. .Net is tested, but does have bugs, which is why MS has a bug reporting site. I'm not convinced this is a bug, but I don't understand the behavior. Inner joins should return the same set regardless of direction, though the order of results may be differ.

Comment: So far you've stated "my comparison code is correct", "either I don't understand how join works, or Join works differently with hash sets, or .NET has a bug".  Well, you understand how joins work, Join does not work differently with hash sets, and .NET does not have a bug, so what you have here is a collection of statements which contradict each other, and one of them has to be wrong. My money is on "my comparison code is correct" being the false statement.

Comment: @NetMage Individual instances of MyClass *may* return a different hash code than a matching ISearchKey (in the case where I first encountered this problem they both returned the same hash code) but in the join I specify an IEqualityComparer<ICoreKey> whose GetHashCode() **WILL** return the same value for matching MyClass and ISearchKey instances, even if their native hash codes do not match. In simple terms, ICoreKey is a set of values in MyClass and ISearchKey which MUST match before there is a chance for equality. If the core values match then the Equals does a partial key match.

Comment: @EricLippert The IEqualityComparer<ICoreKey> is correct.  I have HEAVILY tested it. That is what I thought was the problem to begin with and it was only after a lot of testing that I examined the join itself.  If the IEqualityComparer<ICoreKey> is wrong, wouldn't i get the wrong result whether I used searchKeys.Join( _mySet...) or _mySet.Join(searchKeys...)?  I don't.  searchKeys.Join( _mySet...) returns 1 MyClass per searchKey,   _mySet.Join(searchKeys...) returns ALL the MyClass that match the searchKeys.   I've done a LOT of joins and normally A.join(B) == B.Join(A), but not with hash sets.

Comment: Well then, my advice continues to be: **create the minimal code that reproduces the defect**. You should be able to get this down to a few dozen lines of extremely clear code that we all can run on our machines. When you do so, either you'll find your mistake, or you will have a program that someone else can find the mistake, or, you'll have a clear repro for your bug report to Microsoft.

Comment: Also, use science. You have a hypothesis: joins are wrong with hash sets.  OK, so start trying stuff.  **Make a copy of the hash set into a list and run the test again**.  Did you get a different result? That's evidence for your hypothesis. But if you got the same result then your hypothesis is false and should be abandoned.

Comment: @EricLippert You keep claiming I said joins are broken. I *NEVER* made that claim, and I ask you to stop saying I did. I *observed* different behavior when joining a List<T> to a HashSet<T> than I've seen when joining other collection types (ex: List to List). The join isn't symmetrical, the order determines whether you get 9 records back or 215 (actual results). That is odd for an *inner* join. Maybe that's defined behavior for HashSet<T> with collisions on the hash codes. If so, I'm cool with that, but there's nothing in the documentation about that. Which is why I asked my questions.

Comment: It's not the expected behaviour. That would be seriously broken. **It is not observed to happen in correct code.** That sort of thing is observed to happen in code where the comparison logic violates the rules of equality. Again: make a small reproducer that clearly demonstrates the behaviour, and you'll find your bug.

Comment: Another way you might try to find your bug is to attack the equality problem directly. For example: make your comparison mechanism accumulate a list of every input it receives. When that list gets to be, say, 1000 items, then go into a verification mode. For every item in the list, verify that A = A is true. For every pair of items in the list, verify that A = B is the same as B = A. For all of those where it is true, check  whether A = C matches B = C for every C. Worst case, that's only a billion checks. Then reset and accumulate another 1000.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your bug is almost certainly somewhere in the vast amount of code you did not show in the question. My advice is that you simplify your program down to the *simplest possible program that produces the bug*. In doing so, either you will find your bug, or you will produce a program that is so simple that you can post all of it in your question and then we can analyze it.

> Assuming the behavior is correct, I would greatly appreciate someone explaining the underlying logic behind this (unexpected) Join/HashSet behavior.

Since I do not know what the unexpected behaviour is, I cannot say why it happens. I can however say precisely what `Join` does, and perhaps that will help.

`Join` takes the following:

- An "outer" collection -- the receiver of the `Join`.
- An "inner" collection -- the first argument of the extension method
- Two key extractors, that extract a key from the outer and inner collections
- A projection, that takes a member of the inner and outer collections whose keys match, and produces the result for that match
- A comparison operation that compares two keys for equality.

Here's how `Join` works. (This is *logically* what happens; the actual implementation details are somewhat optimized.)

First, we iterate over the "inner" collection, exactly once.

For each element of the inner collection, we extract its key, and we form a multi-dictionary that maps from the key to the set of all elements in the inner collection where the key selector produced that key.  Keys are compared for equality using the supplied comparison.

Thus, we now have a lookup from `TKey` to `IEnumerable<TInner>`.

Second, we iterate over the "outer" collection, exactly once.

For each element of the outer collection, we extract its key, and do a lookup in the multi-dictionary for that key, again, using the supplied key comparison.

We then do a nested loop on each matching element of the inner collection, call the projection on the outer/inner pair, and yield the result.

That is, `Join` behaves like this pseudocode implementation:

```
static IEnumerable<TResult> Join<TOuter, TInner, TKey, TResult>
  (IEnumerable<TOuter> outer, 
  IEnumerable<TInner> inner, 
  Func<TOuter, TKey> outerKeySelector, 
  Func<TInner, TKey> innerKeySelector, 
  Func<TOuter, TInner, TResult> resultSelector, 
  IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer) 
{
  var lookup = new SomeMultiDictionary<TKey, TInner>(comparer);
  foreach(TInner innerItem in inner)
  {
    TKey innerKey = innerKeySelector(innerItem);
    lookup.Add(innerItem, innerKey);
  }
  foreach (TOuter outerItem in outer) 
  {
    TKey outerKey = outerKeySelector(outerItem);
    foreach(TInner innerItem in lookup[outerKey])
    {
      TResult result = resultSelector(outerItem, innerItem);
      yield return result;
    }
  }
}
```

---

Some suggestions:

- Replace all your `GetHashCode` implementations so that they return `0`, and run all your tests. They should pass! **It is always legal to return zero from `GetHashCode`.** Doing so will almost certainly wreck your *performance*, but *it must not wreck your correctness*.  If you are in a situation where you *require* a particular non-zero value of `GetHashCode`, then you have a bug.
- Test your key comparison to ensure that it is a valid comparison. It must obey the three rules of equality: (1) reflexivity: a thing always equals itself, (2) symmetry: the equality of `A` and `B` must be the same as `B` and `A`, (3) transitivity: if `A` equals `B` and `B` equals `C` then `A` must equal `C`. If these rules are not met then `Join` can behave weirdly.
- Replace your `Join` with a `SelectMany` and a `Where`. That is:

  `from o in outer
  join i in inner on getOuterKey(o) equals getInnerKey(i)
  select getResult(o, i)`

can be rewritten as

```
from o in outer
from i in inner
where keyEquality(getOuterKey(o), getInnerKey(i))
select getResult(o, i)
```

That query is *slower* than the join version, but it is *logically* exactly the same.  Again, run your tests. Do you get the same result? If not, **you have a bug somewhere in your logic**.

Again, I cannot emphasize strongly enough that your attitude that "Join is probably broken when given a hash table" is what is holding you back from finding your bug. Join isn't broken. That code hasn't changed in a decade, it is very simple, and it was right when we wrote it the first time. Much more likely is that your complicated and arcane key comparison logic is broken somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for this amazing clear answer Eric -- it shows how my answer was wrong since I assumed you did not iterate over the inner selector.  I do have one question -- HashSet (at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) says HashSet cannot contain duplicate elements.  Are duplicate elements determined by equity operator?  Could that have an effect?  Or an effect in the `lookup[outerKey]` in your code?

Comment: @Hogan: We *require* that if two elements are *equal* then their hash codes must be equal. A hash set detects an attempt to add a duplicate by first hashing the proposed new element and checking to see if there are any elements already in the hash set that have that hash code. If the answer is "no", then there are no duplicates because unequal hashes imply "not equal". If there are hash collisions then each possible collision is checked for equality with the proposed new item, and only if none are equal is the new item added.

Comment: @Hogan: The lookup does something similar to the keys and values. When you add a new [key, value] pair to the lookup, the first thing it does is hashes the new key and checks to see if the lookup key set already contains a key with that hash. If so, then it checks for equality; that's how it knows which value set to insert the new value into. Then a similar process happens on the values.

Comment: @EricLippert So the multi-dictionary maps from key to unique values? The `IEnumerable<TInner>` won't have duplicates? I don't see where `Grouping.Add` does that?

Comment: @NetMage: Oh, good catch; that's a really good question.  You know, I just recently wrote my own multidictionary that had that property and so it was on my mind.  Offhand I do not recall what the built-in lookup does but I believe it allows duplicates in the values set.

Comment: @NetMage: I checked. It allows duplicates in the values, as you'd expect.

Comment: @EricLippert As I did, but not you ;) LOL

Comment: @EricLippert, I now realize I didn't read your initial answer closely enough. The bug was in my IEqualityComparer, which I wrongly insisted was correct. The need for partial matches caused transitivity to fail, which meant the initial the loop over the inner hashset returned false when it should have returned true. Rule 1: Never swear the problem isn't in a particular chunk of code, because it will always be in that code. I couldn't see a way to fix the comparer to handle partial matches against a set of searchkeys, so I refactored code to avoid join. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @RBDavidson: You're welcome. "Select isn't broken" can be a hard lesson to learn, and I've re-learned it many times. (And in my case it is exacerbated because I cannot rely on "the compiler probably isn't broken"! :-) )

Comment: @EricLippert Regarding my claim that "Either I don't understand how the Join method is supposed to work or...."   Well, I *didn't* understand how the Join method worked. I assumed Join only compared items in the outer collection against those in the inner. I didn't know it looped over the inner collection first, comparing those elements against each other. When I confirmed the behavior matched your explanation, I realized there would be cases where ISearchKey would equal two different MyClass instances which would not equal each other. Thanks for enlightening me on the Join method's logic.

Comment: @RBDavidson: If you don't build an inner-key-lookup table then the join operation is `O(inner * outer)` in the sizes of the inner and outer sequences. If you do build the key lookup then the join operation is `O(inner + outer)` which is almost always much better. But making that optimization requires that the key set be partitioned into equivalence sets, which requires an equivalence relation, which requires transitivity.

Comment: @RBDavidson: Further reading: If the subject of "ways people implement comparisons wrong" interests you, see https://ericlippert.com/2011/01/20/bad-comparisons-part-one/.  If the subject "ways people implement GetHashCode wrong" interests you, see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode/