# Using GetHashCode of IEqualityComparer the right way

Tags: c#, linq, hashcode, comparable

When using `IEqualityComparer` to compare objects in a collection, I'm not sure which one of the followings approaches is the best one.

Here is the implementation :

```
class CarComparer : IEqualityComparer<Car>
{
    public bool Equals(Car x, Car y)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Car car)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

And here are my two options for `GetHashCode` implementation

```
    public int GetHashCode(Car row)
    {
        return HashCode.Combine(row.Name, row.Color , row.Size);
    }
```

Or,

```
    public int GetHashCode(Car row)
    {
        return row.GetHashCode();
    }
```

I don't like the first one because it make code less maintainable and probably less expensive in terms of resources. But a lot of people use it like that.

I would like to use my `CarComparer` in linq functions later. Like this:

```
cars.Distinct(new CarComparer());
```

**Which one should I use?**

Is this an opinion based question?

Comment: Presumably you're implementing an `IEqualityComparer<Car>` because `Car` itself does not implement `GetHashCode` and `Equals` the way you want it to (that's basically the only reason you'd write an `IEqualityComparer<T>`). In that case, surely `Car.GetHashCode()` doesn't do what you want, and therefore there's no point in delegating to it

Comment: Yes @canton7, for example using the .Distinct() method would not work without a custom comparer (linq)

Comment: If you want to use the implementation of `Car`'s `GetHashCode` and `Equals` there's no reason to implement a custom `IEqualityComparer<Car>`. You should implement that interface if you need a custom logic to compare your objects.

So override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` then.

Comment: thanks @TimSchmelter please see my answer to canton7 comment

Comment: @BorisDetry Your comment doesn't help I'm afraid. Do you want to use `Car`'s implementation of `GetHashCode` or not? If you want to use it, you don't need a custom `IEqualityComparer<Car>`. If you don't want to use it, don't call it (from within your `IEqualityComparer<Car>`)

Comment: @BorisDetry: answered that in my answer

Comment: I did a little update on the question @canton7, hope it helps

Comment: @BorisDetry Why don't you override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` in your `Car` class? That way you don't need an `IEqualityComparer<Car>`

Comment: @canton7 I guess that should work too, but how do I implement GetHashCode() in car class? Way one or two?

Comment: @BorisDetry Well, calling `this.GetHashCode()` inside your Car's `GetHashCode()` method would lead to a stack overflow.... Calling `base.GetHashCode()` does exactly the same thing as not overriding it at all, which is obviously pointless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer:

When using LINQ the `GetHashCode` is called **before** the `Equals` method **and only when the result of the `GetHashCode` is equal for two items in the collection.**

So `GetHashCode` must be override too :

```
  public int GetHashCode(Car row)
{
    return HashCode.Combine(row.Name, row.Color , row.Size);
}
```

[See full response here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22453032/iequalitycomparer-gethashcode-being-called-but-equals-not)